# Show that $\frac p{a^n}-\frac q{b^n}-1=0$.

Tags: polynomials

If  $x^n-py^n-qz^n$ is exactly divisible by $x^2-(ay+bz)x+abyz$ , then prove that $\frac p{a^n}-\frac q{b^n}-1=0$

Comment: Any thoughts on the problem?

Comment: @DanZimm You may try to use factor theorem for solving this problem.

Comment: Are u sure it is $p/a^n-q/b^n=1$. I think it should be $p/a^n+q/b^n=1$.

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay no i am sure that my question is correct.But if you think it should be $p/a^n+q/b^n=1$ then please send your answer according to it.

Comment: I have just given an answer.

Comment: thanx for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Erom the second quadratic we can see that the roots are $$\alpha=ay,\beta=bz$$ which implies that they are roots of $x$ for the first equation also. So, we get the equations $$a^ny^n=py^n+qz^n\\
b^nz^n=py^n+qz^n$$ Hence, $$ a^ny^n=py^n+q(ay)^n/b^n\Rightarrow p/a^n+q/b^n=1$$

Comment: Mukhopa Can you plz explain how did u derive $a^ny^n=py^n+q(ay)^n/b^n⇒p/a^n+q/b^n=1 $

Comment: Just divide both sides by $(ay)^n$

Comment: thanx for help I got it